# printing treeview to a printer tkinter

Tags: tkinter, printing, treeview

hello i have a treeview that shows records from database on a frame and i have been searching online if i can make this tree view printable. but  i couldn't find any form of answer.

if nothing worked i was planning to just print on a text editor which would look awful.

my question is if there is a way to have a treeview and is text editor the only way to make it work(printable)?

it doesn't have to be specifically treeview if there are different solutions. since i just want to keep the table formatting of treeview.

Comment: I think you have no much choice, but since the data comes from a database, have you thought about using reportlab?

Comment: do you have any go to place for understanding report labs? and how to work with them.

i was wondering if i have a pre-made word file with a format that i want to print the stuff can i access it with report lab then position the text i want to use(i just barely looked up reportlab)